# GridBagLayout difficulties

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I would like to layout components as shown in the picture only using the `GridBagLayout`.
I have tried several constraints but it never end up with the expected result so I come to wonder if it is truly possible with only the `GridBagLayout`.  The difficulty is for the C1, C2 and C3 components.
C1 and C2 are `JComponent` that will hold other components inside like `JPanel`.  I have set their minimum and preferred size. C3 is a `JButton`.
C1 should not take extra space so i set its weightx to 0 and gridwidth to 1 (tried also with 2 as it span on C2 and C3).
C2 takes all extra space, i set its weightx to 1 and gridwidth to 3.
The GUI is not resizable.
I have use this `LayoutManager` several times but still don't master it, thank you for a little help.

[image: GridBagLayout]

Comment: 1) Put some context to areas C1, 2 & 3.  What is in those areas?  2) Is it supposed to be resizable?  Where should extra space & height be assigned to the GUI?

Comment: right(as @Andrew Thompson mentioned), have to put there invisible JComponents, or JLabel, but have to set GBC properly, or you can to create an matrix(take smalest dimmension) of JLabels on the top, then use only numbers of GBC columns for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I'll talking only about `GridBagLayout`, even this could be job exactly for `MigLayout` (MigLayout has additional parameter for fills numbers of Columns & Rows, resize, e.i.), and/or `TableLayout(???)`
- `GridBagLayout` required only filling all desired numbers of columns in first row(only), then matrix is created and you can to define whatever `GBC weightx, weighty, gridx, gridy` and/or with `Anchor` too
- example talking about

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GbcLayout {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("GbcLayoutGbcLayout");
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel hidelLabel;
    private JLabel firstLabel;
    private JTextField firstText;

    public GbcLayout() {
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        for (int k = 0; k < 50; k++) {
            hidelLabel = new JLabel("     ");
            hidelLabel.setOpaque(true);
            hidelLabel.setBackground(Color.orange);
            hidelLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 0.5;
            gbc.weighty = 0.5;
            gbc.gridx = k;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            panel.add(hidelLabel, gbc);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            firstLabel = new JLabel("Testing Label : ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            firstLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
            firstLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 8;
            gbc.gridy = k + 1;
            panel.add(firstLabel, gbc);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            firstText = new JTextField("Testing TextField");
            firstText.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
            firstText.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
            gbc.gridx = 9;
            gbc.gridwidth = k + 8;
            gbc.gridy = k + 1;
            panel.add(firstText, gbc);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            firstLabel = new JLabel("Testing Label : ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            firstLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
            firstLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
            gbc.gridx = 20 + k;
            gbc.gridwidth = 8;
            gbc.gridy = k + 1;
            panel.add(firstLabel, gbc);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            firstText = new JTextField("Testing TextField");
            firstText.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
            firstText.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
            gbc.gridx = 29 + k;
            gbc.gridwidth = 21 - k;
            gbc.gridy = k + 1;
            panel.add(firstText, gbc);
        }
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                GbcLayout gbcl = new GbcLayout();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it's impossible. `GridBagLayout` can't figure out what's the proper distance between the start of C1 and start of C3.